# Highcharts change pointPlacement through javascript

Tags: highcharts

I would like to change the pointPlacement of a series through javascript. Is this possible?

```
series: [{
                    name: ' Margin',
                    color: '#FF3300',
                    yAxis: 1,
                    data: .....,
                    pointPlacement: 0.15
                }]
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use [series.update()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Series.update) and change this paramaeter to any.